# Need advice with php/html on displaying MySQL data

Tags: php, html

So I created this script to test out if I could output from my database. And it works fine inside the php, but when I trying extracting that data inside a div tag in HTML, it does not work. Any suggestions, thanks.

```
//Connection to database, working fine, top of page
<?php
require "include/mysql.php";
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>

//This is also working as intended
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `LISTINGS` ORDER BY `LISTINGS`.`YA` DESC";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){

    echo $record['TITLE'];

}
?>

//Here is were the problem, in the H2 tag, i'm trying to output a title but it is not working. 
<div class="cards-row">

    <div class="card-row">
        <div class="card-row-inner">
            <div class="card-row-image" data-background-image="assets/img/tmp/product-1.jpg">


            </div><!-- /.card-row-image -->

            <div class="card-row-body">
                <h2 class="card-row-title"><?php echo $record['TITLE'];?>title</h2>
                <div class="card-row-content">Description</div><!-- /.card-row-content -->
            </div><!-- /.card-row-body -->

            <div class="card-row-properties">
                <dl>

                        <dd>Test</dd><dt>Visit Website</dt>
                        <dd>Test</dd><dt>More Info</dt>                  
                        <dd>Added</dd><dt>AddedDate</dt>
                        <dd>Visited</dd><dt>Visited</dt>

                </dl>
            </div><!-- /.card-row-properties -->
        </div><!-- /.card-row-inner -->
    </div><!-- /.card-row -->


</div><!-- /.cards-row -->
```

I know there is a lot of unfinished code but im just testing a few things out at the moment, sorry for bad grammar.

Comment: so if one the answer is acceptable  for you, mark it  please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access `$record` outside of the while loop. If there is only one record you want to access just get rid of the loop and write `$record = mysql_fetch_array($myData);` on its own.

Comment: Literally, i figured that our 10 secs before you commented, i'm dum. Thanks anyways

Comment: Or, alternatively, put the whole <div thingy> clause within the while loop.

Comment: @FelipeLopez No problem. It's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: One more question, as @Gralgrathor said, when i out the entire div tag inside the while loop there is many errors, any ideas that could be causing  it

Comment: Could you provide the specific error? @PeppiAlexandrova has provided some code that does that so maybe compare your code with theirs.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't close the first <?php before putting my html in, I didn't know I had to close it. If you see the code you can see how he added a closing line in while loop and at the end of the div tag. Anyways, thank you both

Answer (score 2):

And if there are many rows move the html inside the while loop:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `LISTINGS` ORDER BY `LISTINGS`.`YA` DESC";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
?>



<div class="cards-row">

<div class="card-row">
    <div class="card-row-inner">
        <div class="card-row-image" data-background-image="assets/img/tmp/product-1.jpg">


        </div><!-- /.card-row-image -->

        <div class="card-row-body">
            <h2 class="card-row-title"><?php echo $record['TITLE'];?>title</h2>
            <div class="card-row-content">Description</div><!-- /.card-row-content -->
        </div><!-- /.card-row-body -->

        <div class="card-row-properties">
            <dl>

                    <dd>Test</dd><dt>Visit Website</dt>
                    <dd>Test</dd><dt>More Info</dt>                  
                    <dd>Added</dd><dt>AddedDate</dt>
                    <dd>Visited</dd><dt>Visited</dt>

            </dl>
        </div><!-- /.card-row-properties -->
    </div><!-- /.card-row-inner -->
</div><!-- /.card-row -->
<?php 

}
?>
```